Any good applications to graph a Cartesian Coordinate 3D plane with the Z axis as imaginary?
Apologies if this is confusing or worded incorrectly. I would like a graphing application that can graph in the 3D plane with real numbers on the X and Y axis and imaginary numbers on the Z axis. Does such a thing exist? I am looking for one because I am curious about the graph in the video below:
https://youtu.be/T647CGsuOVU?si=MuMR3k0TKt7-CZW9
I understand that it was aftereffects, but it would be cool if there was a graphing application that could do this. Thank you so much!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To graph a function $\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$, you really need 4 dimensions, because the input and output are both 2-dimensional. To work around this, you can graph the real and imaginary parts of the function output as two separate graphs. WolframAlpha does this automatically: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=graph+z%5E2+%2B+1
